# Upload image to Firebase through .NET Core Razor pages

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-storage, razor-pages

I'm trying to upload image to Google Firebase using .NET Core Razor pages. I have no trouble with the actual upload. But for some reson the file is 0 kb after being uploaded. Also I get no exceptions or any other errors.

**upload.cshtml**

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input name="photo" class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/*" />
   <input type="submit" value="Add product" />
</form>
```

**upload.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task OnPostAsync(IFormFile photo)
{
       var path = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "Uploads", photo.FileName);
       var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);
       await photo.CopyToAsync(stream);
       FileName = photo.FileName;

       var task = new FirebaseStorage("[project_name].appspot.com")
                         .Child(FileName)
                         .PutAsync(stream);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I at last managed to upload to Google Firebase.

```
var file = Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "uploads", Product.Upload.FileName);
                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await Product.Upload.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                    }

                    // FirebaseStorage.Put method accepts any type of stream.
                    var stream = System.IO.File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);

                    //Get file extension
                    string ext = Path.GetExtension(Product.Upload.FileName);

                    // you can use CancellationTokenSource to cancel the upload midway
                    var cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();

                    //Upload image to Google Firebase Storage
                    var task = await new FirebaseStorage([project_name].appspot.com,
                    new FirebaseStorageOptions
                    {
                        ThrowOnCancel = true
                    })
                    .Child("[folder_name]")
                    .Child($"IMAGE_{Guid.NewGuid()}{ext}")
                    .PutAsync(stream, cancellation.Token);

                    //Closing stream inorder to delete image from server
                    stream.Close();
```